# Slow Page after parsing RSS

Tags: php, rss

Any ideas on how to parse RSS feeds without massively slowing down my page?

It takes a good 3 secs to load whilst it grabs the RSS from another server.

Comment: Please post your RSS parsing code (or at least a sample of it) to see how it can be improved. Are you using http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php ?

Comment: http://apptools.com/phptools/xml/rss.php

Comment: Use PubSubHubbub and get the data pushed to you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a script that will run in cron with 10 min interval (depending on your preference). That script fetches the RSS feeds, storing the data in your server so that your page will get the feeds locally.

Comment: Don't do this! It's polling and it sucks... use something to get the data pushed from each of these RSS feeds pushed to you, with a tool like http://superfeedr.com